# How to make function act on (multiple) replacement variables

Tags: functions, replacement, rule, arguments

I have a function which returns an algebraic expression corresponding to a "jump" between two ordinates, for example $[x]=x_2-x_1$. The function applies for any choice of variables and labels. The function in question is this:

```
Jump[expr_, i1_, i0_] := Module[{varsD},
  varsD = Complement[Variables[expr]];
  ReplaceAll[expr, # -> Subscript[#, i1] & /@ varsD] - 
   ReplaceAll[expr, # -> Subscript[#, i0] & /@ varsD] ]
```

Alternatively, I could create one with a single argument and fixed labels:

```
Jump12[expr_] := Jump[expr, 1, 2]
```

What I would like to do is find a way so that, if the function is performed with a single argument, and then that argument is replaced with several others, then the result is the same as if Jump12 was applied to the new combination.

To make it clearer:

[image]

How can I modify the jump function so that the output is equivalent to the first result in both cases?

(An application of this result is if I have a partial differential equation with some dependent variable $u$, and I want to non-dimensionalise by rescaling $u=\cal{U} \hat{u}$  at a later stage, after the original equation was already posed.)

Comment: Why not ask how to nondimensionalize a PDE instead?

Comment: Because I already have a framework in place that does that, bar this odd quirk.

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal but maybe it fits your needs. You can add this definition:

```
Jump[var_Symbol -> expr_, i1_, i0_] := Module[{varsD},
  varsD = Complement@Variables@expr;
  {
   Subscript[var, i1] -> ReplaceAll[expr, # -> Subscript[#, i1] & /@ varsD],
   Subscript[var, i0] -> ReplaceAll[expr, # -> Subscript[#, i0] & /@ varsD]
   }
  ]
```

And now:

```
Jump12[x] /. Jump12[x -> y z]
```

> Subscript[y, 1] Subscript[z, 1] - Subscript[y, 2] Subscript[z, 2]